# Problem during installing Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I want to install Kali Linux on my hard disk. I already have Ubuntu/win7 dual boot. When I start installing Kali Linux everything goes right, choosing  language, root's pass word ..., but after the system finished coping "system's files" I got a weird black screen saying system is going for halt (or something like that I can't remember well because it was too short).

After that I lost the grub, I got an error saying "File Not Found grub-rescue >". I retried but the same problem came up, so I installed Ubuntu again and everything is fine right now.

I would like to know the reason why I cant have Kali Linux on my hard drive though it works awesome in live mode.

P.S I disabled wireless card from BIOS menu because the installation stops at detecting network interfaces step.

Comment: Please provide some more information on GRUB installation in Ubuntu and Kali.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `debootstrap` to install Kali directly from Ubuntu.

You may refer here: http://docs.kali.org/armel-armhf/kali-linux-arm-chroot (replace armhf with your arch).

You will also have to use this installation script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/master/assets/home/deploy/debootstrap/scripts/kali

You should specify it in this line:

```
debootstrap --foreign --arch $architecture kali kali-$architecture \
    http://archive.kali.org/kali <place_path_to_downloaded_script_here>
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can have Kali on your hard drive together with Ubuntu and Windows. Your problem is most likely wrong partitioning scheme or grub configuration during the setup process.

Comment: I want to delete ubuntu and install kali linux instead. here is what i did: I deleted ubuntu partition and I formatted it with ext4 files system and I chose it as Kali's partition. thats all I did and I dont think there is something wrong here.  
Thanks for your reaction.

Comment: @Younes If you want to install Kali in place of Ubuntu, using `debootstrap` will not be so straightforward. I guess you could accidentally install grub to your partition (/dev/sda1 or so) instead of your MBR (/dev/sda). That would cause your issue